# Why can't I access the vector?

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, structured-bindings

I am currently trying to access the vector defined as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
template<class T>
class file
{
    public:
        typedef vector<vector<T> > buffer;
};


int main()
{
    file<double> test;
    cout << test.buffer.size() << endl;


    std::vector<pair<string, file<double> > > list_of_files;

    for (const auto& [name, file] : list_of_files)
    {
        cout << file.buffer.size() << endl;
    }

}
```

the error message I am getting is that scoping the `buffer` like I am currently doing is invalid?, but why is it invalid? I don't see a reason why it should be?

I am in the for loop trying to iterate between the inner and outer vector  of the `buffer`, but since I can't scope it, I am not able to access? How do i access it?

Comment: `buffer` is not a vector. It is a typedef, which means that you can later declare a vector with `buffer myBuffer;` as shorthand for `vector<vector<T>> myBuffer;`. But your class doesn't have a vector yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because the code declares `buffer` as a new type for `vector<vector<T>>`. If you want `buffer` to be a member of `file`, you can do so like this:

```
template<class T>
class file
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> buffer;
};
```

After changing that, `main()` should compile without errors.